# Substituting the value of variable inside backtick operator

Tags: ruby

How can I substitute the value of a variable inside the backtick operator?

```
script_dir = File.expand_path File.dirname(__FILE__)
p `ruby -e p "$script_dir"` # this does not work
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Ruby, unlike Perl, the dollar sign indicates a global variable, not a plain regular variable to expand in a string.   In a string, you need to use the #{} construct:

```
p `ruby -e "p #{script_dir}"`
```

An example:

```
irb(main):011:0> str = '\'howdy\''
=> "'howdy'"
irb(main):012:0> `ruby -e "p #{str}"`
=> "\"howdy\"\n"
```

Comment: I am using ruby version 1.8.7 on fedora machine, the above statement does not work. It outputs ""

Comment: did you make sure your script_dir variable has the proper value?

Comment: Also, the argument to -e must be in quotes, edited.  You also have to be careful about quoting, since the argument to p must be in quotes it it's a string literal: script_dir = '\'foo\''

Comment: some correction. The output of *** p `ruby -e p "#{script_dir}"` *** is "". The output of *** p `ruby -e "p #{script_dir}"` is -e:1: unterminated string meets end of file
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_END, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tREGEXP_END or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR
""
. The script_dir is defined and has value.

Comment: What you should do is echo the entire string you want to use inside the backticks and take a look at it to make sure it is correct.   The version I have now in the answer works assuming script_dir contains the proper quote characters itself escaped in the string.   Because you're running a print command, the parameter you pass to print must be quoted if it is a string literal.

Comment: I tried *** script_dir = "\"hello\""
p `ruby -e "p #{script_dir}"` *** and *** script_dir = "hello"
p `ruby -e "p #{script_dir}"`
***. Both did not work, i get the error -e:1: undefined local variable or method `hello' for main:Object (NameError)
""

Comment: Check the latest edit it gives another example.   You have to be careful with quoting if you want to use the print command in your ruby script executing within the backtick

Answer (score 21):

Ruby [string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) works with backtick operator:

```
p `ruby -e p "#{script_dir}"`
```